# Lookup value in csv/txt Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my high_schools.csv file I have this:

```
high_school,City,State,zipcode,latitude,longitude
EPISCOPAL,BOISE,ID,83701,43.6,-116
```

I want to see if a value exists and then return the zip, latitude, and/or longitude

This is what I have so far but it's checking for the entire row instead of just the beginning.

```
def find_voucher(high_school, city,state,filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        return ("{0},{1},{2}".format(high_school,city,state)) in f
```

When I run this it will return as False because it is matching the entire row and not just the first 3 columns.  How could I change it to match the first part and return the entire row or just the zipcode, latitude, longitude?

```
find_voucher('EPISCOPAL', 'BOISE', 'ID', 'C:/high_schools.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csv` module.

**Demo:**

```
import csv

def find_voucher(high_school, city,state,filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            if [high_school, city,state] == line[:3]:
                return line[3:] 

print( find_voucher('EPISCOPAL', 'BOISE', 'ID', filename) )
```

**Output:**

```
['83701', '43.6', '-116']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to convert your rows into dictionaries, then you can explicitly check the values you pass in with simple lookups.

**Code:**

```
from csv import DictReader

def find_voucher(high_school, city, state, filename):
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = DictReader(csvfile)

        for row in reader:

            # check the arguments against the row
            if (row['high_school'] == high_school and
                row['City'] == city and
                row['State'] == state):

               return dict(row)
```

**Output:**

```
{'high_school': 'EPISCOPAL', 'City': 'BOISE', 'State': 'ID', 'zipcode': '83701', 'latitude': '43.6', 'longitude': '-116'}
```

In **Python 3.6**,  `DictReader()` returns a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), so you can just wrap `dict()` to return a normal dictionary. If this doesn't bother you, you can just leave it as `return row`, since an `OrderedDict()` is  just an ordered dictionary.

Comment: Not working for me, here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624249/using-csv-dicreader-gives-error-valueerror-dictionary-update-sequence-element

Answer (score 1):

You need to write an if statement, to check the values you pass in:

```
def find_voucher(high_school, city, state, filename):
   with open(filename) as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     for row in reader:
        if row[0] == high_school and row[1] == city and row[2] == state:
             return row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# import pandas as pd
import pandas  

# load 1st row of the csv file into the df
df = pd.read_csv('high_school.csv', nrows = 1)

# lock the slice of the loaded df which matches the condition. the condition is set for the column value being in the list of expected values
df = df.loc[(df['City'].isin(['BOISE']))]

# return the needed columns from sliced dataframe
df = df.iloc[:,[3,4,5]]
```

Comment: please add some explanation

Comment: the code is self explanatory. there is more comments than code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas module.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
row = df.query('high_school == "EPISCOPAL" & City=="BOISE" & State=="ID"')
```

row here is dataframe like this:

```
  high_school   City State  zipcode  latitude  longitude
0   EPISCOPAL  BOISE    ID    83701      43.6       -116
```

You will get the required row and you can return whatever column values you want from it.
Saves you writing all the loops.